# Parsing semi-unstructured text file with Python. Keeping some rows and pivot others

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, data-structures, file-format

I have a file with decent structure, but the dates of subsequent events (one or more) are only printed once. I can't figure out how to read the file, recognize dates, and the map them to each game result that follows, until the next date appears.

The data looks like this:

```
Sa 19.11.2016 
FC Tuggen
FC Basel 1893 II 
1
3

SC Cham 
FC Zürich II 
0
1

SC Kriens
FC Köniz  
3
1

Sa 26.11.2016 
FC Bavois
SC Brühl  
1
4

Mi 30.11.2016 
FC Zürich II
FC Basel 1893 II 
2
2
```

Each date can apply to one or more game results. I've tried reading through the file and grepping dates

```
keys = []
for line in d:
    if line[0:2] in ('Sa','So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr'):
        keys.append(line[2:-1].strip())
```

But then I don't know how to assign the same date to the games the follow, until the next date arrives. For this I've tried various combinations of enumerate(), xrange(), etc. enumerate() didn't work how I tried because I could only add the first game after each date.

My desired output looks as follows, or a defaultdict(list) with keys as the date and array elements as small dictionaries:

```
Sa 19.11.2016,FC Tuggen,FC Basel 1893 II,1,3
Sa 19.11.2016,SC Cham,FC Zürich II,0,1
Sa 19.11.2016,SC Kriens,FC Köniz,3,1
Sa 26.11.2016,FC Bavois,SC Brühl,1,4
Mi 30.11.2016,FC Zürich II,FC Basel 1893 II,2,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simply as the following might work, assuming that the input file has a format similar to what you have shown. Keep track of the last seen date using a variable.

```
lastseendate = None
gameinfo = []

for line in f:
    if line[0:2] in ('Sa','So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr'):  # date row
        lastseendate = line.strip()
    elif len(line.strip()) == 0:  # empty line
        print(lastseendate + ',' + ','.join(gameinfo))  # print out the row for game just read before
        gameinfo = []  # ready to read the next game info
    else:
        gameinfo.append(line.strip())
```

If the leading two characters before the date are too many to hardcode, then you could use a regular expression like below.

```
import re
pat = re.compile("[A-Za-z] \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}")
```

Then replace the `# date row` line with

```
if pat.match(line):
```

#### EDIT

1. This piece of code does not print the info of the last game in the file unless there is an empty line at the end of the file. To fix this, either add an empty line at the end of the file or repeat the print statement after the loop ends.
2. Removed `\n` in the print statement (unnecessary as `print` already prints new line).

Comment: there are a couple good answers, but this one is the simplest, most explicit, and also worked right out of the box (I just had to add a newline to the end of my text file). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8 :


def parse(it):
  record, date = [], ""
  for line in it:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
      if len(record) > 1:
        yield ",".join(record)
      if date:
        record = [date]
      continue
    if line.startswith(('Sa', 'So', 'Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr')):
      if len(record) > 1:
        yield ",".join(record)
      date = line
      record = [date]
      continue

    record.append(line)

  if len(record) > 1:
    yield ",".join(record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  input = """
Sa 19.11.2016
FC Tuggen
FC Basel 1893 II
1
3

SC Cham
FC Zürich II
0
1

SC Kriens
FC Köniz
3
1

Sa 26.11.2016
FC Bavois
SC Brühl
1
4

Mi 30.11.2016
FC Zürich II
FC Basel 1893 II
2
2
"""
  output = """Sa 19.11.2016,FC Tuggen,FC Basel 1893 II,1,3
Sa 19.11.2016,SC Cham,FC Zürich II,0,1
Sa 19.11.2016,SC Kriens,FC Köniz,3,1
Sa 26.11.2016,FC Bavois,SC Brühl,1,4
Mi 30.11.2016,FC Zürich II,FC Basel 1893 II,2,2
"""
  for record, expected in zip(parse(input.splitlines()), output.splitlines()):
    assert record == expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ok, misread the problem earlier.This one works with all the provided data, I just didn't want to take up all that space in my code on SO.

First, I split the text by line. Going through each line I do a couple of things. One, I keep track of start lines, which are the first line and any line after an empty line. An empty line also sets the needDate flag to true.

For lines that aren't empty, I use a regex to search for a date. If I find one, its set as the (current) date. Otherwise, I check if needDate is set (due to the previous line being empty) and if so append the date to that line.

Then I grouped the lines, with each start line starting a group using my subList function, then I joined grouped lines with commas.

```
tf = """Sa 19.11.2016
FC Tuggen
FC Basel 1893 II
1
3
"""

import re

i=0
sl=[0] #start lines
gnu = True
dlt = False # date last turn
lines = tf.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line == '':
        regex = re.search('[A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', line)
        if regex:
            date = regex.group(0) 
            dlt = True
        elif needDate:
            lines[i] = date + ',' + line
        needDate= False
    else:
            sl.append(i+1)
            needDate = True
    i += 1

def subList(lzt, inds):
    tups = []
    for i in range(len(inds)):
        if i < len(inds)-1:
            tups.append( (inds[i], inds[i+1]))
        else:
            tups.append( (inds[i], len(lzt)))
    return [lzt[s:e] for s,e in tups]

ans = []
for x in subList(lines, sl):
    ans.append(",".join(x[:-1]))

for line in ans:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative copes, whether or not there is a blank line at the end. The essential idea is to send an additional token representing end-of-file, which could be redundant.

```
class Token:
    def __call__ (self, token):
        if len(token) == 0 or token=='-':
            print (','. join(self.content))
        if token[0:2] in ('Sa','So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr'):
            self.content = [token]
        else:
            self.content.append(token)

token = Token()

with open('football.txt') as football:
    for line in football.readlines():
        token(line.strip())
    line = football.readline()
    token('-')
```

Result:

```
Sa 19.11.2016,FC Tuggen,FC Basel 1893 II,1,3
Sa 19.11.2016,FC Tuggen,FC Basel 1893 II,1,3,,SC Cham,FC Zürich II,0,1
Sa 19.11.2016,FC Tuggen,FC Basel 1893 II,1,3,,SC Cham,FC Zürich II,0,1,,SC Kriens,FC Köniz,3,1
Sa 26.11.2016,FC Bavois,SC Brühl,1,4
Mi 30.11.2016,FC Zürich II,FC Basel 1893 II,2,2
```